# Not able to instantiate object from TLBINF32

Tags: excel, vba, typelib, tlbinf32

I have downloaded tlbinf32.dll and added it as a reference to VBA but it doesn't seem to be working, when I try to create the following object

```
     Dim oTLI As Object

     Set oTLI = New TLI.TLIApplication
     Set oTLI = CreateObject("TLI.TLIApplication")
```

I get the following error for both

*'ActiveX component can't create object'*

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: have you registered it using RegSvr?

Comment: There used to be a now deleted answer that read, *"If you are running 64-bit, you will not be able to use the 'tlbinf32.dll' - you need 32-bit to do so..."*.

Comment: This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42581513/11318818) details how to use tlbinf32.dll from 64-bit Office