# tlbinf32.dll in a 64bits .Net application

Tags: com, tlbinf32

It seems there is no 64 bits version of `tlbinf32.dll`, this (old) COM DLL is used to extract informations of COM components. (see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23364324/3205529) )

I need to access it from a 64 bits C# application.
I did not manage to host it into a separate surrogate process, I'm still obtaining the exception  `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` . My code works for x86 platforms but I have to implement it also for 64 bits.

Can any one help me by providing a step by step procedure to launch it into a surrogate (`Dllhost`) - or maybe another way to use it ?

Do you know a better alternative to browse trough all methods, classes.. of a native COM Dll ?

Comment: It is not very clear what you expect anybody here to do about it.  Finding an alternative is not difficult, all of these interfaces are available in .NET in the System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes namespace.  The only extra thing you need is the [pinvoke declaration of LoadTypeLib()](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/oleaut32/LoadTypeLib.html).

Comment: I m trying to discover dynamically the methods, arguments, enumeration, class of a Com DLL. The `tlbinf32.dll` is very convenient to this end (see the SO answer mentioned above) , the System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes namespaces semms much more cumbersome as I need to go trough all the IDispatch and to use IntPtr that need to be marshalled.

Comment: @Hans sorry the link to the API of tlbinf32.dll was wrong, I removed it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- open Windows' "Component Services"
- open nodes to "My Computer/COM+ Applications"
- right-click, choose to add a new Application
- choose an "empty application", name it "tlbinf" for example
- make sure you choose "Server application" (means it will be a surrogate that the wizard will be nice to help you create)
- choose the user you want the server application to run as (for testing you can choose interactive user but this is an important decision to make)
- you don't have to add any role, not any user
- open this newly created app, right-click on "Components" and choose to add a new one
- choose to install new component(s)
- browse to your tlbinf32.dll location, press "Next" after the wizard has detected 3 interfaces to expose

That's it. You should see something like this:

[image]

Now you can use the same client code and it should work. Note the performance is not comparable however (out-of-process vs in-process).

The surrogate app you've just created has a lots of parameters you can reconfigure later on, with the same UI. You can also script or write code (C#, powershell, VBScript, etc.) to automate all the steps above.

Comment: Perfect, simple, **effective** and clear ! Does it work for all x86 native COM DLL that I need to call from x64 ?

Comment: @Malick - some DLL may not work (if they don't handle marshaling properly for example), but the principle is valid for all.

Comment: For VBA at least, this means CreateObject/ Dim As New TLIApplication will now use the 64bit COM+ application to make the object, so it should just work with no changes to code