# Windows COM: Client 32bit C++ native application vs. server .NET 6 out-of-proc registry-free possible?

Tags: .net, com, out-of-process, reg-free

We have an old large 32bit C++ application (created with Borland C++ Builder 5) on its memory limits. We would like to have it call modules written in C# that reside in another process. With .NET 6, Microsoft propagated .NET COM servers and registry-free (!) access from a client, but the examples show a .NET client with in-process access only. The [documentation "COM activation for .NET Core on Windows"](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/COM-activation.md) is not very clear about whether it is possible, it says:

> COM activation in this document is currently limited to in-proc scenarios. Scenarios involving out-of-proc COM activation are deferred.

Microsoft demos:

- [Reg-free, but .NET client, in-proc](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/extensions/COMServerDemo)
- [Native client/.NET server, out-of-proc, but not reg-free](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/samples/out-of-process-com-server/)

Is it possible to achieve this? Out-of-process is mandatory, and registry-free is very important to us because of deployment issues we would have otherwise.

I still hope I get things running with a manifest file for the client.

### Addendum

#### Out-of-Process

The out-of-process part seems to come for free anyway: When I register (`regsvr32`) my .NET dll (built for target AnyCPU), it can be called from my 32bit native app. Because AnyCPU means 64bit for COM on a 64bit Windows, it automatically starts the built-in surrogate process dllhost.exe.

#### Registry-free

So my remaining task is the registry-free configuration with application manifests.
It turns out we already have a manifest for registry-free COM with some 3rd party OCX controls, but unfortunately, adding the entry from Microsoft's working reg-free example (.NET7 server and .NET7 client) does not work. What I did was adding the following reference to the already existing application manifest of the native client:

```xml
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="DllServer.X" version="1.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

I put the build output from the COM server to the build output of the client, along with it the client's manifest `DllServer.X.manifest` which is referenced from the code above:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0"
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="DllServer.X" version="1.0.0.0" />
    <file name="DllServer.comhost.dll">
        <comClass clsid="{af080472-f173-4d9d-8be7-435776617347}" threadingModel="Apartment" />
    </file>
</assembly>
```

At runtime, activating the server class (CoCreateInstance) fails with HRESULT 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG) which is irritating because the same client code works with a registered COM server, and the client code should not be affected here.
If I exchange the dependency tag above in the client application manifest by another tag which originates from `DllServer.X.manifest` as follows

```xml
    <file name="DllServer.comhost.dll">
        <comClass clsid="{af080472-f173-4d9d-8be7-435776617347}" threadingModel="Apartment" />
    </file>
```

(and all the already working existing COM references in our app manifest actually look like this), the CoCreateInstance call at runtime fails with: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG).

Same with the [Microsoft out-of-proc example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/samples/out-of-process-com-server/) as base with the following changes:

1. Make the DllServer project registry-free by adding `<EnableRegFreeCom>True</EnableRegFreeCom>` next to the EnableComHosting tag.
2. Compile the project and copy its output to the NativeClient's output directory.
3. Create a new file `NativeClient.manifest` in the NativeClient project directory with the following contents (with or without the assemblyIdentity for NativeClient does not seem to make a difference):

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <!-- https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/sbscs/assembly-manifests -->
   <assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <!-- <assemblyIdentity
       type="win32" 
       name="NativeClient"
       version="1.0.0.0" /> -->

     <dependency>
       <dependentAssembly>
         <!-- RegFree COM matching the registration of the generated managed COM server -->
         <assemblyIdentity
             type="win32"
             name="DllServer.X"
             version="1.0.0.0"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
     </dependency>
   </assembly>
   ```
4. Compile the NativeClient project (I changed it to x86 with the Configuration Manager because this is what we have here, and it eases the out-of-proc case if the COM client is 64bit due to the automatic COM surrogate involvation).
5. Embed manifest in client EXE: Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt, cd to the NativeClient directory and execute:

   ```
   mt.exe -manifest NativeClient.manifest -outputresource:..\Debug\NativeClient.exe;1
   ```
6. Run the Client. For me, it says `CoCreateInstance failure: 0x80040154` 
   Why? What is the correct application manifest?

In the log produced by `sxstrace trace -logfile:sxstrace.etl` the NativeClient did not even show up.

By the way: providing the ManagedClient with the manifest file via reference in the project file actually works, but we need it for the native client.

Comment: Yes it's possible, .NET core supports all COM features but things are not necessarily built automatically. You don't need to write out of process servers to enabled 32=>64 communication, you can host .dll in a "surrogate" process. Windows provides one for free, Component Services. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/42581513/403671 demonstrates 64=>32 but it's exactly the same idea.

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you, that looks intriguing. However, the out-of-process part seems to come for free anyway: When I register my .NET dll (built for target AnyCPU), it can be called from my 32bit native app. Because AnyCPU means 64bit for COM on a 64bit Windows, it automatically starts the builtin surrogate process dllhost.exe. So I am left with the registry-free configuration with application manifests.

Comment: AnyCPU is great and indeed works fine if you register in both world, but it only works for a .NET Framework dll, not for .NET core which has a mydll.comhost.dll entry. And it has nothing to do with a 32 bit client calling a 64 bit server, it's impossible to load a 64bit dll in a 32bit process (and reverse). For that you need either an out-of-proc server, or a surrogate.

Comment: In a client => oop server, you have only two processes, the client (in any bitness provided everything is properly configured and marshaled) and the server (in any bitness provided everything is properly configured and marshaled). And they are communicating with RPC. There's no dllhost involved because there's no need for it since there's already two processes. dllhost is not involved w/o configuring the need for it (either by config/surrogate registry or using Windows Component Services). If you have a reproducing project, it would be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thoughts, @SimonMourier! I have created a fork of Microsoft's demo code with a new branch "RegFreeOutOfProc" on https://github.com/Vizehase/dotnet-samples/tree/RegFreeOutOfProc
Here I have changed files in the core/extensions/OutOfProcCOM directory, and I have added a Markdown file https://github.com/Vizehase/dotnet-samples/blob/RegFreeOutOfProc/core/extensions/OutOfProcCOM/OutOfProcRegFree.md describing what I have changed and done.
Now I will try to create a surrogate from your descriptions from the other thread.

Comment: This is fairly complex to rebuild and test. Instead I've created a more simple sample of 32b native calling 64 bit managed all reg-free here: https://github.com/smourier/RegfreeNetComServer

Comment: @SimonMourier Merci beaucoup! That does it, it is excellent work! So the main changes to what I have seen before are:

1. We start the server EXE explicitly, which starts its services without any Windows registration requiring elevated privileges.
2. The client has a manifest with the UUID reference of the TLB and to the server interface/proxy stub class; almost the same as in the server manifest.
3. The client starts and calls CoCreateInstance in the usual way.

Could you please post this as an official answer to my question such that I can mark it as solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM does allow 32bit <=> 64 bits cross-process communication between clients and servers. It "just" requires them to properly implement marshaling: proxy / stub for IUnknown-derived interfaces and/or type libraries (.tlb) for IDispatch-derived interfaces.

The difficulty with reg-free COM is it's *relatively* recent (more than COM itself) and poorly supported by tooling and documentation.

The idea is really for COM servers and COM clients to *declare*:

- as a COM server, what services (COM objects, COM interfaces) they serve
- as a COM client, what services they need

And both sides also need to declare how connection will work, which is how these interfaces will be marshaled across processes, possibly including satellite files or embedded resources.

To "*declare* this, both sides use [Application manifests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests), to enable COM to find the same information it would have found looking in the registry, but now without using it.

I've made a full working sample here on github: [RegfreeNetComServer](https://github.com/smourier/RegfreeNetComServer). In this sample, the server application manifest looks like this:

```
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <!-- server name can be anything but must not collide with client -->
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="RegfreeNetComServer.app"/>

    <!-- this means hey, "there's a satellite file I come with" -->
    <file name="server.tlb">
        <!-- this means "and it contains a typelib with this id" -->
        <typelib tlbid="{46F3FEB2-121D-4830-AA22-0CDA9EA90DC3}"
          version="1.0" helpdir="" />
    </file>

    <!-- this is for an IDispatch-derived interface named "IServer" -->
    <comInterfaceExternalProxyStub
      iid="{F586D6F4-AF37-441E-80A6-3D33D977882D}"
      name="IServer"
      tlbid="{46F3FEB2-121D-4830-AA22-0CDA9EA90DC3}"
      proxyStubClsid32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
    
    ... other things
</assembly>
```

For the client, it's the same, but the identity (the client's app) is obviously different:

```
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <!-- client name can be anything but must not collide with server -->
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="NativeClient.app" type="win32" />

    <!-- the rest is identical since the tlb file is the same in this case -->
    <file name="server.tlb">
        <!-- this means "and it contains a typelib with this id" -->
        <typelib tlbid="{46F3FEB2-121D-4830-AA22-0CDA9EA90DC3}"
          version="1.0" helpdir="" />
    </file>

    <comInterfaceExternalProxyStub
      iid="{F586D6F4-AF37-441E-80A6-3D33D977882D}"
      name="IServer"
      tlbid="{46F3FEB2-121D-4830-AA22-0CDA9EA90DC3}"
      proxyStubClsid32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
</assembly>
```

In my sample, the tlb is in an external "server.tlb" file, and this file must simply be present aside both client and server .exe, but it can also be embedded as a Win32 resource in each of these. .NET 6+ allows this, Visual Studio C++ allows this for native projects.

If your reg-free configuration is really invalid, you'll get Windows' MessageBox alerts with errors. The easier to fix is to check the Event Viewer / Application tab which contains quite informative events.