# Can 64-bit Excel VBA use VB6 ActiveX?

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

I have some old ActiveX controls and DLLs written in VB6 that interact with some Excel VBA code. We have always recommended that people use the 32-bit version of Excel, but I thought I'd have another go at getting this to work in 64-bit.

Is this possible?

The objects are created in the VBA code using CreateObject (late binding), but this fails when using the compiled ocx/dll. If I run the code in the VB6 IDE though, it can create the object with no problem.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42569377/11683?

Comment: Thanks. That looks interesting. I guess I need to do some reading up on COM+

Comment: I tried this with one of our OCXs. 'Install new component' didn't work, but 'Import components that are already registered' seems to have worked. At least, VBA can now create the object. Unfortunately, I'm now getting error - Non-modal forms cannot be displayed in this host application ....

Comment: The general approach of using an out of process COM surrogate is probably the only practical way to do this.

Comment: https://twinbasic.com/ is getting close to being able to recompile VB6 in 64-bit, potentially that could work here if you are able to rebuild.

Comment: I suggest migrating the code to VB.NET. We migrated a 30,000-line Excel COM add-in, using the free VBUW. We used the VBUW again a year later, to migrate a 400,000-line desktop suite.